# first build of maven project with jenkins failed

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am trying to start my first build on Jenkins, but it failed, since I am a beginner, even I got those console output, still don't know how to solve the problem, anyone can help me?jenkins version: 1.6.0.4 JDK: 1.8.0   maven:3.5.0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEE21.png)

Comment: Jenkins 1.604 sounds a little bit old...furthermore put the pom file of your project in the root of the jenkins workspace....Furthermore the output shows something which is wrong `DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE`???

Comment: what do you mean "the root of the jenkins workspace"? my current path for pom is: C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\flightsbooking,  if I need to change to the root of the jenkins workspace, how should I find the path? or if I may setup the root in jenkins?

Comment: Your pom file is a subfolder flightsbooking and not in workspace...Your checkout does so...

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug opened with maven 3.5.0

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43446

Downgrading the maven to any old stable version, i.e., 3.2.5 or 3.3.1, would make it work.